Link between $i$ and the $\pi/2$-Rotation Matrix
What is the exact relationship between a rotation matrix and multiplication by a complex number, when we represent complex numbers as matrices?
To clarify the idea: $i$, in matrix form, is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which corresponds to the rotation matrix for an angle of $\pi/2$. However, to transform the coordinates of a point $(x, y)$, we multiply it by the matrix, and do not consider this point in its complex form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x & -y \\
y & x
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Could you explain how these two representations are connected?
First Idea
Let $\mathbb{C} := \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}, a, b \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$, and we define the following isomorphism:
$$
\begin{align*}
p :& \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \\
&z \mapsto z \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
We then find that if $z = \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ is its associated point, then:
$$
p(iz) = iz \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = i \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -b \\ a \end{pmatrix}
$$
which corresponds exactly to the result of a real rotation.
However, this vector space isomorphism does not seem very natural and appears purely ad hoc.

The $\pi/2$-rotation applied to the complex plane moves $i$ to $1$. Therefore the joke" The number you have dialed is imaginary. Please rotate your phone by $\pi/2$." The matrix form of $i$ is a different matter.

$(x+iy)i=-y+xi$ corresponds to $\pmatrix{x&-y\y&x}\pmatrix{0&-1\1&0}=\pmatrix{-y&-x\x&-y}$

The correspondence
The correspondence is this: a pair of real numbers $(x, y)$ can be thought of as a point in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ or as the coordinates of the complex number $z = x + iy$ in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. Just as the the real plane has a standard basis
$$
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\},
$$
the complex plane also has the corresponding standard basis (as a real vector space)
$$
\bigl\{ 1, i \bigr\}.
$$
Multiplication
Now consider an arbitrary $w = u + iv \in \mathbb{C}$. What happens when we multiply (on the left, say) by $z$?
$$
zw = (x + iy)(u + iv) = (xu - yv) + i(yu + xv).
$$
This new complex number has real part $xu - yv$ and imaginary part $yu + xv$. Notice that each of these (real) quantities is a (real) linear combination of the original (real) parts $u$ and $v$.
This looks like a linear transformation! In fact, if we instead stack the parts vertically to make column vectors, then it's clear that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
x & -y \\
y & x
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
u \\
v
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 
xu - yv \\
yu + xv
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Geometric perspective
It's helpful to have a geometric sense of this as well. For this, let's look at multiplication by a particular complex number: $z = i$. Since $z = 0 + i\,1$, this corresponds to the rotation matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Recall the way that a matrix acts on the basis: each column is the image of the given basis vector under the transformation. So, the matrix calculation
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
corresponds to the fact that $i\,1 = i$ (duh!), and similarly for the second column,
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 
-1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
corresponds to the fact that $i\,i = -1$, as expected. By linearity, this "right angle rotation" acting on an arbitrary vector looks like
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
u \\
v
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 
-v \\
u
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which recovers the "rotation" formula
$$
i\,(u + iv) = -v + iu.
$$
Of course an arbitrary complex number can be decomposed into its real and imaginary parts:
$$
z = x + iy = (x + i0) + (0 + iy), 
$$
so the corresponding matrix similarly decomposes as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{pmatrix} 
x & -y \\
y & x
\end{pmatrix}
&= \phantom{x}\begin{pmatrix} 
x & 0 \\
0 & x
\end{pmatrix}
+
\phantom{y}\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -y \\
y & 0
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= x \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
+
y\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
$$
This last form shows that the linear transformation corresponding to complex multiplication can be broken up as a linear combination of the identity (scaled by real quantity $x$) and the rotation (scaled by $y$).

Your idea is correct. The standard approach to introduce $\mathbb C$ is to define a multplication on the $2$-dimensional real vector space $\mathbb R^2$ (i.e. on the plane $\mathbb R^2$) by
$$(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ac-bd,ad + bc).$$
Then $\mathbb C = (\mathbb R^2,+,\cdot)$ is easily seen to be a field with multiplicative neutral element $(1,0)$. The set $\overline{\mathbb R} = \{(a,0) \mid a \in \mathbb R \}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb R$ which is usually identified with $\mathbb R$ via the obvious isomorphism $a \mapsto (a,0)$. It is standard practice, albeit an abuse of notation, to write $a = (a,0)$. With $i := (0,1)$ we can then write each $z = (a,b) \in \mathbb C$ in the form $z = a + ib$.
Another commonly used way to introduce the complex numbers is to consider the unitary ring $M(\mathbb R,2)$ of real $2\times2$-matrices and to define
$$\overline{\mathbb C} = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix}\ \middle|\ a, b \in \mathbb  R\right\} \subset M(\mathbb R,2) .$$
It is easy to check that $\overline{\mathbb C}$ is a commutative unitary subring of $M(\mathbb R,2)$ which is actually a field.
It is also easy to verify that
$$\gamma : \mathbb C \to \overline{\mathbb C} , \gamma(a+ib) = \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix}$$
is an isomorphism of fields.
At first glance this isomorphism (which allows to understand complex numbers as real $2\times 2$-matrices) may appear rather ad hoc, but this is not true. It has a clear geometric interpretation.
Multiplication by a complex number $z$ gives a $\mathbb C$-linear map $\mu_z : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, \mu_z(w) = z \cdot w$. Clearly each $\mathbb C$-linear map $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ has the form $f = \mu_z$ where $z = f(1)$. Thus $z \mapsto \mu_z$ gives an isomorphism $\mu$ from $\mathbb C$ to the $\mathbb C$-vector space $\mathcal L(\mathbb C)$ of $\mathbb C$-linear maps $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$. This shows in particular that $\mathcal L(\mathbb C)$ is a field isomorphic to $\mathbb  C$.
This gives a twofold interpretation of complex numbers: They can be understood as vectors in the plane $\mathbb C$ as well as $\mathbb C$-linear maps on $\mathbb C$ which are applied to vectors in the plane $\mathbb C$. From the abstract algebraic perspective both interpretions are equivalent (via the isomorphism $\mu : \mathbb C \to \mathcal L(\mathbb C)$).
Each $\mathbb C$-linear map $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is automatically an $\mathbb R$-linear map $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$. Let us see what the matrix representation $A_z \in  M(\mathbb R,2)$ of $\mu_z$ looks like. Actually, if $z = a + ib$, we easily verify that
$$A_z =  \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix} .$$
To see this, consider $w = c + id$. Then $\mu_z(w) = z \cdot w = ac - bd + i(ad + bc)$. Regarding $w$ and $\mu_z(w)$ as a vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ means to write $w = \begin{pmatrix} c \\ d\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mu_z(w) = \begin{pmatrix} ac - bd \\ ad +bc \end{pmatrix}$. But clearly
$$A_z \cdot \begin{pmatrix} c \\ d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ac - bd \\ ad +bc \end{pmatrix} .$$
That is, the above isomorphism $\gamma : \mathbb C \to \overline{\mathbb C} $ arises very naturally by associating to a complex number $z$ the matrix $A_z \in   M(\mathbb R,2)$.
The matrices $A \in \overline{\mathbb C}$ with determinant $1$ (i.e. with $a^2 + b^2 = 1$) are rotation  matrices. In fact, we can write $a = \cos \phi$ and $b = \sin \phi$ with a unique $\phi \in  [0,2\pi)$. Applying $A$ to $v \in \mathbb R^2$ gives the vector $A \cdot v$ obtained from $v$ by a counterclockwise rotation through the angle $\phi$.
If $\lvert z  \rvert = 1$, then $\det A_z = 1$ so that $A_z$ is a rotation matrix. For $z = i$ we get $A_ i = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ which describes a rotation through $\pi/2$.
For $z \ne 0$ let $r = \lvert z \rvert$ and $z' = z/\lvert z \rvert$. Then $A_z$ is the matrix of a spiral similarity composed of a rotation desribed by $A_{z'}$ and a dilation with factor $r$.
Appendix.
Concerning the above algebraic considerations we can be a bit more formal. For $\mathbb K = \mathbb R, \mathbb C$ let us agree to write vectors $v \in \mathbb K^n$ as column vectors $v =  \begin{pmatrix} v_1  \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}$, i.e. as $n \times 1$-matrices. By $\mathcal L(\mathbb K,n)$ we denote the $\mathbb K$-vector space of all $\mathbb K$-linear maps $f : \mathbb K^n \to \mathbb K^n$. It becomes a unitary ring with multiplication $f \cdot g = f \circ g$, where $\circ$ is the usual composition of functions. Linear maps can be represented by matrices in the well-known way which results in the standard isomorphism of unitary rings
$$\lambda : \mathcal L(\mathbb K,n) \to M(\mathbb K,n) = \text{ ring of $n \times n$-matrices with entries in $\mathbb K$}$$
characterized by the property that $f(v) = \lambda(f) \cdot v$ for all $v \in \mathbb K^n$, where $\cdot$ denotes matrix multiplication. The matrix $\lambda(f) \in M(\mathbb K,n)$ is known as the matrix representation of $f \in \mathcal L(\mathbb K,n)$.
Clearly the unitary ring $M(\mathbb K,1)$ is a field which is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb K$ via $\theta : \mathbb K \to M(\mathbb K,1), \theta(z) = (z)$.
Multiplication by a complex number $z$ gives a $\mathbb C$-linear map $\mu_z : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, \mu_z(w) =  w \cdot z$. Clearly each $\mathbb C$-linear map $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ has the form $f = \mu_z$ with a unique $z \in \mathbb C$. In fact, $z = f(1)$. Just observe that scalar multiplication $w \cdot z$ on the $\mathbb C$-vector space $\mathbb C$ agrees with the multiplication $w \cdot z$ in the field $\mathbb C$. This yields $f(w) = f(w \cdot 1) = w \cdot f(1)$ by $\mathbb C$-linearity.  Thus $z \mapsto \mu_z$ gives a bijection $\mu : \mathbb C \to \mathcal L(\mathbb C,1)$. It is easy to check that $\mu$ is actually a field isomorphism. The composition $\lambda \circ \mu : \mathbb C \to M(\mathbb C,1)$ is nothing  else than the canonical $\theta$ considered above.
Each $\mathbb C$-linear map $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is automatically an $\mathbb R$-linear map $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$. In other words, we have an inclusion of $\mathbb R$-vector spaces
$$\mathcal L(\mathbb C,1) \subset \mathcal L(\mathbb R,2) .$$
As already shown above, the matrix representation $A_z \in  M(\mathbb R,2)$ of $\mu_z \in \mathcal L(\mathbb C,1) \subset \mathcal L(\mathbb R,2)$ is given by
$$A_z =  \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix} .$$

In fact it is common to use the canonical bijection:
$$\begin{aligned}
\Bbb R \times\Bbb R &\to \Bbb C\\
(x, y)&\mapsto z=x+iy
\end{aligned}$$
This is often called the complex plane or Argand plane or Gauss plane.
As soon as you consider that complex plane, the link between a product of a complex by $i$ and the $\frac\pi 2$ rotation of its image in the complex plane becomes evident.
For the same reason the product by an arbitrary $z=a+ib$ complex number, maps naturally in the complex plane to the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$
